# Calculate two to the power of decimal

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, arithmetic, exponentiation, big-numbers

I have a decimal number $a$ with integer and fractional parts as follows:

$$ a_{int} = a_0 + a_1 2 + a_2 2^2 + \cdots $$
$$ a_{fr} = \frac{a_{-1}}{2}  + \frac{a_{-2}}{2^2} + \cdots  $$

I want to compute $b=2^a$. The problem is that $a$ is very big so I want to implement the power function by myself. I have two questions:

1. What is the most efficient way to calculate $b$?
2. If I want to get only the integer part of $b$, how much precision do I need to have in $a_{fr}$? In other words, how the precisions of $b$ and $a$ are related?

Comment: Ultimately you have to use $2^x=\exp(\ln(2)·x)$. There are tricks to reduce $a$ to a small $x$, such as finding a point close to $a$ in the set of integer linear combinations of $1$, $\log_23$, $\log_25$. // You need $[a]+1$ correct bits in the result, add an amount between $d$ and $\log_2d$ for the working precision where $d$ is the number of arithmetic operations with non-integer operands. // Look at the `bc` math library, it has the most basic implementation for multi-precision calculator functions.

Comment: The most efficient way — both with respect to the actual calculations and also with respect to implementing them — will almost likely be to use already existing algorithms and arbitrary-precision arithmetic like [GNU MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/). $2^x$ is implemented as [`mpfr_exp2`](https://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#Transcendental-Functions).  Notice that many other programming languages provide GMP/MPFR bindings.